# How to replace the rectangle(DIP) bridge rectifier with round one.

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, rectifier, triac, dimmer

I want to make an AC dimmer and the circuit diagram from the instructables uses a bridge rectifier which is in DIP package and rectangle in shape and the rectifier which I have is round one, so how can I connect it in the circuit replacing the rectangular one?

instructable - http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-controlled-light-dimmer-The-circuit/?ALLSTEPS

[image: Round one]

[image: rectangular one]

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the modifications of the circuit board to a minimum I would recommend to get another DIP socket (6 pins), remove the unneeded pins, cut the wires of the round rectifier to an appropriate length and solder the them to the DIP socket. Finally plug the DIP socket to the PCB. Be sure to watch for the proper pinout though, but since everything is labeled that should be quite easy.

Always assuming that the current and voltage ratings of the new rectifier are appropriate. As pointed out by Spehro Pefhany, the voltage rating of the W005M (round) is lower than the rating of the DF02 (DIP), so this needs to be checked against the supply voltage before changing the parts.

Comment: Is there any problem if I interchange the places of ~ marked pins?

Comment: No, see my comment in the other answer.

Comment: The DIP socket is only 6 pins, with the middle pin on each side removed.

Comment: @TanishqJaiswal - you might find that a 4-pin DIP bridge rectifier is cheaper than a DIP socket. It may as easy to get too.

Answer (score 2):

They're clearly marked with ~, ~, + and -. There is no difference between the two ~ terminals. You can probably bend the leads of the WOxx to fit but it won't be pretty.

Comment: I don't know where to connect that ~,~. Is there any problem If I interchange them?

Comment: No, they're interchangable. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier "Full wave rectifier" to understand that both AC connectors work the same.

Comment: Just connect the wires marked +/- to where the +/- pins on the missing DIP bridge would go. The other two wires go to the ~ (in either order). The bridge you show does not appear to be suitably rated for voltage.